# how Ruby on Rails production server processing request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, production-environment

In ROR local development, I'm able to process the request one by one. ( Example: if two users open two different page at the same time each request are handled one by one) but in production, many users are able to open same or different page at same time. How will ROR server handles request in production server?

Comment: Simply its depends on your server please follow this link, this will help you more https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/a-comparison-of-rack-web-servers-for-ruby-web-applications

Comment: @MayurShah feel free to post this as an anwser. The OPs question is a bit too broad for a single SO question.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://blog.appsignal.com/2016/03/17/ruby-magic-mastering-concurrency.html) is a good article I found sometime ago which explain different types of concurrency models

Answer (score 0):

Simply, Its **depends on the server** that you use for the application. [Follow this link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/a-comparison-of-rack-web-servers-for-ruby-web-applications), this will help you more.